# How to allow 2-line if statements using clang-format

Tags: c++, lint, code-formatting, clang-format

I am working on setting up a style format check for a large library. Currently, our team styleguide prefers that instead of one line if statements, we use a "2 line" statement, which looks like this

```cpp
if(statementIsTrue)
{  printf("True");  }
else
{
   anExampleBlock = true;
   elsestatement.function();
}
```

Note how the if block is partially indented to 2 spaces, to line up with the else statement. The style's indentation is 3 spaces. In addition, there are 2 spaces between the semicolon and the close brace for symmetry purposes.

Other thing to note about the style. braces *always* go on a new line. That is the intention behind the above. For all if statements, functions, classes, etc. the opening brace goes on a new line.

How can we adjust clang-format to perform this task?

EDIT: More examples of blocks

```cpp
/**
 * This is just example code for formatting, not meant to be useful code
 */
bool testFunction(int largeNumber, int randomNumber)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < largeNumber; j++)
   {
      if (j == randomNumber)
      {  return true;  }
      else
      {  print("not found");  }
   }
}

int main()
{
   //Three space indentation (tab characters should not be used anywhere)
   //Single space should exist between if, else if, for, while, etc. and (...)
   if (testFunction(testParm1, testParm2))
   {
      print("Hello");
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: My advice is change your style guide. That is very hard to read. Make the if like the else.

Comment: Posted another example to clarify. I understand this is not a common style, but this is a very old library, that would not be easy to change style for. Looking for a solution to actually format this

Comment: If you use clang-format you can write your own rules, relatively easily.

Comment: in clang-format, how would i write this?

Comment: "would not be easy to change style" yet you're looking to use a code formatter on it. If you like it that way I guess more power to you. Seems like a huge hassle to go from a one line to multiline and vice versa/ *shrug*

Comment: The purpose of the request is to enforce the current style, and help newer developers with this very uncommon style, and prevent other _simple_ style mistakes from getting into the code

Comment: *in clang-format, how would i write this?*  The source code to clang-format is available.  You'd write this by writing your rules into clang-format's source code.  Then you can submit your changes as a *pull request* to the maintainers of clang-format.  In the meantime, you can use your customized one-off clang-format with your own idiosyncratic formatting quirks.  (I've done the same.)

Comment: Oh my god. OP is asking how to do a specific, objective thing in a common tool. Everyone is saying in comments, "You do it by doing it." How do they do it? This question should never have been closed. It's not opinion based. It's a clear question with an objective answer.

Comment: @JohnFilleau When I voted to close this, the question was _"Is there any formatter that can handle this? And what would the configuration look like?"_ - but I'll vote to reopen now that it's specifically about clang-format.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well in that case... I feel quite silly.

Comment: @JohnFilleau :-) No need. It _was_ a good rewrite of the question by OP.

Comment: Sorry yes, rewrote the question to be specifically about clang-format :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you edit your `.clang-format` file in your project repo with the following settings, it should work.

Please note - I haven't tested this, but reading the documentation, I felt this would be suitable.

```
BreakBeforeBraces:Allman,
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always,
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
```

If this doesn't work, experiment with possible options for these fields available at [Clang-format style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Hope this helps!

Here is an online tool which I found where you could play around with your code trying out various options:
[clang-format configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/)

[image: Sample experiment with your code snippet]

Comment: Hi, this does not work. The settings you provided result in this 

```
if (_c)
{
   anotherVariable = nullptr;
}
if (_a)
{
   anotherVariable = "baz";
}
else
{
   anotherVariable = "bar";
}
```

Comment: The formatting is not working, but the blocks end up being 4 lines long, instead of the intended 2

Comment: The expected output is not clear from the original question. Please post snippet of how your current code look like and how you want it to be displayed.

Comment: Added some more information in the my response. Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not help. Notice how your output is different than my expected output